# Find element by its clone with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, dom

Here is the problem. I have a container with `li` elements. I clone one element with `.clone()`, append it to other node and then try to find the original element by this clone, but it does not seem to be working this way.
Currently I was only able to implement it with `:contains()` content filter.

So the question is, does jQuery consider cloned elements to be equal, or if not, which would be the best way to find them?

[Link to jsfiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/hLn7D/2/)

Comment: can you post your code? Useful if you make [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: No, they are not equal. Assign a unique ID to the original then manually change that ID in the clones, then you can easily get the original.

Comment: @Unknown Check again, I updated the post.

Comment: why do you need to find it? you already have a reference to $el

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is not the same. As reported [JQuery api](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) for clone():

> Clone() Create a deep copy of the set of matched elements.

So, contents of two li is the same (style too) but it are different object.

And if you try to add:

```
$('ul').append($el2);
```

before changing css, you'll see this difference.

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hLn7D/4/)

Comment: Thanks, I suspected so. Just thought, maybe jQuery still could recognize clones internally.